# Why isn't my UITableView appearing when I begin to type in the custom UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to make a custom `UISearchBar` that has a `UITableView` appear beneath the `UISearchBar` when a user begins typing; However, right now when the typing begins, there is nothing that appears. I added print statements and they are printing the text as it is changed. What needs to be changed so that the `UITableView` appears?

**SuggestionSearchBar**

---

```
import UIKit

class SuggestionSearchBar: UISearchBar, UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    var suggestionTableView = UITableView(frame: .zero)
    let allPossibilities: [String]!
    var possibilities = [String]()

    init(del: UISearchBarDelegate, dropDownPossibilities: [String]) {
        self.allPossibilities = dropDownPossibilities
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        delegate = del
        searchTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchBar(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        searchTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_:)), for: .editingDidEnd)
        sizeToFit()
        addTableView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func addTableView() {
        suggestionTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        suggestionTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.75)
        addSubview(suggestionTableView)
        suggestionTableView.delegate = self
        suggestionTableView.dataSource = self
        suggestionTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            suggestionTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            suggestionTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
            suggestionTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),
            suggestionTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
        ])
        hideSuggestions()
    }
    
    func showSuggestions() {
        suggestionTableView.isHidden = false
    }
    
    func hideSuggestions() {
        suggestionTableView.isHidden = true
    }
    
    @objc func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print(searchBar.text!)
        showSuggestions()
        possibilities = allPossibilities.filter {$0.contains(searchBar.text!)}
        print(possibilities.count)
        suggestionTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    @objc func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        hideSuggestions()
    }
    
    
}

extension SuggestionSearchBar: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return possibilities.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = suggestionTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.25, green: 0.25, blue: 0.25, alpha: 0.75)
        if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.75)
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = possibilities[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

**ViewController**

---

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var searchBar = SuggestionSearchBar(del: self, dropDownPossibilities: ["red","green","blue","yellow"])

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpUI()
    }

    func setUpUI() {
        setUpSearchBar()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    func setUpSearchBar() {
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBar.Style.prominent
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.isTranslucent = false
        searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        searchBar.delegate = self
        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
    }
    
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print(searchBar.text!)
    }
    
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You want a table view to appear where?  Where is your view controller?

Comment: @ElTomato I edited the question to include how I implemented it in my ```ViewController```

Comment: Why are you adding a table view to the search bar when in fact you probably want to show it with your view controller?

Comment: @ElTomato I do want it to show with my view controller, but I want this to be use throughout my app and I figured it would be way easier to do if I built it as a its own object with this as a built in feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues to deal with -- but to address the first issue:

*"Why isn't my UITableView appearing..."*

You are adding a tableView as a subview, but you are showing it **outside the bounds** of its superview.

You can easily confirm this by changing the table view's top constraint to this:

```
suggestionTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
```

When you now start typing in the search field, it will become partially covered by the top of the table view.

To get the table view to show, you need to disable `.clipsToBounds` on the table view's superview:

```
func showSuggestions() {
    var sv = suggestionTableView.superview
    sv?.clipsToBounds = false
    suggestionTableView.isHidden = false
}
```

The next issue, though, is that you cannot select a row in the table, because it's still outside the bounds of its superview. To handle that, you'll need to implement `hitTest(...)`, but it's going to be complicated because the **navigation bar** gets the hit, and it will have to pass the hit through to the table.

---

**Edit**

For a more complete example... I changed your `SuggestionSearchBar` to a `UIView` subclass that contains the `UISearchBar` and `UITableView` and all of the associated logic.

I've included comments in the code that *should* make everything pretty clear.

To enable interaction with elements that exist *outside the bounds* of their superview, what you'll need to do is override `hitTest(...)` in **both** the navigation bar and in the custom title view.

One way to make this work is to use a subclassed `UINavigationBar`:

```
class CustomNavBar: UINavigationBar {
    
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        // if the titleView is not an instance of SuggestionSearchBarView
        //  just allow the default hitTest
        guard let t = topItem, t.titleView is SuggestionSearchBarView else {
            return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        }
        
        // loop through subviews, checking hitTest until we find one
        //  this will allow tapping a view outside the bounds of this view
        for v in self.subviews.reversed() {
            if v.subviews.count > 0 {
                for subv in v.subviews {
                    let p = subv.convert(point, from: self)
                    let r = subv.hitTest(p, with: event)
                    if r != nil {
                        return r
                    }
                }
            }
            let p = v.convert(point, from: self)
            let r = v.hitTest(p, with: event)
            if r != nil {
                return r
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
    
}
```

To use that in Storyboard, simply assign the Custom Class of the navigation controller's navigation bar to `CustomNavBar`.

Or, if you're creating the navigation controller via code:

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: CustomNavBar.self, toolbarClass: nil)
```

You *could* probably do the same thing by swizzling `hitTest(...)`, but this is probably a much simpler route.

Here's a modified `SuggestionSearchBar` (now `SuggestionSearchBarView`), along with the associated `UISearchBarDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate` extensions:

```
class SuggestionSearchBarView: UIView {
    
    var didSelect: ((String)->())?
    var searchTapped: ((String)->())?

    private let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    
    private let suggestionTableView = UITableView()
    private let tableHolderView = UIView()
    
    public var allPossibilities: [String] = []
    private var possibilities: [String] = []
    
    private var svClips: Bool = true
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        suggestionTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        suggestionTableView.delegate = self
        suggestionTableView.dataSource = self
        
        searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        suggestionTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableHolderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        addSubview(searchBar)
        tableHolderView.addSubview(suggestionTableView)
        addSubview(tableHolderView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            searchBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            searchBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            searchBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            searchBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            
            // top and height constraints for tableHolderView
            //  leading/trailing will be set in didMoveToSuperview()
            tableHolderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            tableHolderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
            
            suggestionTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableHolderView.topAnchor),
            suggestionTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableHolderView.leadingAnchor),
            suggestionTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableHolderView.trailingAnchor),
            suggestionTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableHolderView.bottomAnchor),

        ])
        
        hideSuggestions()

        // allows the tableView to show outside our bounds
        clipsToBounds = false
        
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBar.Style.prominent
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        searchBar.isTranslucent = false
        searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: false)
        searchBar.delegate = self
        
        // some stylizing
        suggestionTableView.backgroundColor = .white
        suggestionTableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        suggestionTableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        
        tableHolderView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        tableHolderView.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        tableHolderView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
        tableHolderView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
        tableHolderView.layer.masksToBounds = false

    }
    
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        if let sv = superview {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

                // if we want the tableView width to match the searchField
                //tableHolderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchBar.searchTextField.leadingAnchor),
                //tableHolderView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchBar.searchTextField.trailingAnchor),

                // if we want the tableView to span the full view width
                tableHolderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sv.leadingAnchor),
                tableHolderView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sv.trailingAnchor),
                
            ])
            
            // save .clipsToBounds state of superview so we can
            //  restore it when hiding the table view
            svClips = sv.clipsToBounds
        }
    }
    
    func updateTable() -> Void {
        let s = searchBar.text ?? ""
        if s.isEmpty {
            possibilities = allPossibilities
        } else {
            possibilities = allPossibilities.filter {$0.contains(s.lowercased())}
        }
        suggestionTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func showSuggestions() {
        // we need to set .clipsToBounds = false on the superView
        if let sv = superview {
            sv.clipsToBounds = false
        }
        tableHolderView.isHidden = false
        updateTable()
    }
    
    func hideSuggestions() {
        // set .clipsToBounds on the superView
        //  back to its original state
        if let sv = superview {
            sv.clipsToBounds = svClips
        }
        tableHolderView.isHidden = true
    }
    
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        
        // loop through subviews, checking hitTest until we find one
        //  this will allow tapping a view outside the bounds of this view
        for v in subviews.reversed() {
            let p = v.convert(point, from: self)
            let r = v.hitTest(p, with: event)
            if r != nil {
                return r
            }
        }
        
        return nil
        
    }
    
}

// MARK: searchBar Delegate funcs
extension SuggestionSearchBarView: UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        endEditing(true)
    }
    
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        let s = searchBar.text ?? ""
        print("Search Button Tapped:", s)
        // use the closure to tell the controller that the Search button was tapped
        searchTapped?(s)
    }
    
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        showSuggestions()
    }
    
    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        hideSuggestions()
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        updateTable()
    }
    
}

// MARK: tableView DataSource and Delegate funcs
extension SuggestionSearchBarView: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return possibilities.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = suggestionTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.25, alpha: 0.75)
        if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.75)
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = possibilities[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Selected:", possibilities[indexPath.row])
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        endEditing(true)
        // use the closure to tell the controller that a row was selected
        didSelect?(possibilities[indexPath.row])
    }
    
}
```

And here is an example view controller showing its usage:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let searchBar = SuggestionSearchBarView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // titleView width will be auto-sized by navigationBar,
        //  but only if wider than available space
        // so, let's constrain the width to something like 10,000
        //  with less-than-required Priority
        let c = searchBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10000)
        c.priority = .defaultHigh
        c.isActive = true
        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar

        // give the searchBar some suggested values
        searchBar.allPossibilities = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"]
        
        // assign a closure so we can take action when a
        //  suggestion is selected
        searchBar.didSelect = { [weak self] str in
            if let self = self {
                let vc = UIViewController()
                switch str {
                case "red":
                    vc.view.backgroundColor = .red
                case "green":
                    vc.view.backgroundColor = .green
                case "blue":
                    vc.view.backgroundColor = .blue
                case "yellow":
                    vc.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
                default:
                    vc.view.backgroundColor = .white
                }
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }
        }

        // assign a closure so we can take action when a
        //  the Search button is tapped
        searchBar.searchTapped = { [weak self] str in
            print("Search button was tapped....")
            if let self = self {
                // do something
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Please Note: this is ***Example Code Only!!!*** Give it a try... if it seems like it will work for you, give it **lots and lots** of testing!

Comment: Thank you for your response, this fixed my issue. However, I don't know how to implement the hitTest(...). Do you have any suggestions? I can post another question if that would be a better way to ask.

Comment: @helloworld12345 - see the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: I just tried using this, but am having the same problem. I am still not able to click on the TableView

Comment: @helloworld12345 - did you set the custom navigation bar class?

Comment: I believe so. How would you implement that in the ViewController that you posted above?

Comment: @helloworld12345 - sorry... had a typo... in `ViewController` had two lines: `searchBar.didSelect = { ...` the second one should be `searchBar.searchTapped = { ...` I put a working example here: https://github.com/DonMag/SearchBarDropDown