# How to tell if UITableView in custom UISearchBar is touched?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar, hittest

I am trying to create a custom UISearchBar that is placed as the `titleView` of a `navigationController`. Using the following code, the `suggestionTableView`  of suggestions appears perfectly; however, It does not recognize any taps. In fact, it is like the `suggestionTableView` isn't even there because my taps are being sent to another view under the suggestion `suggestionTableView`. I was told that I could use `hitTest(...)` to catch these touches, but I don't know how I would implement this in my `SuggestionSearchBar` or in my `ViewController`. How can I send these touches to the `suggestionTableView`?

**SuggestionSearchBar**

```
class SuggestionSearchBar: UISearchBar, UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    var suggestionTableView = UITableView(frame: .zero)
    let allPossibilities: [String]!
    var possibilities = [String]()
    //let del: UISearchBarDelegate!
    
    init(del: UISearchBarDelegate, dropDownPossibilities: [String]) {
        self.allPossibilities = dropDownPossibilities
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        delegate = del
        searchTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchBar(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        searchTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_:)), for: .editingDidEnd)
        sizeToFit()
        addTableView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func addTableView() {
        let cellHeight = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "").frame.height
        suggestionTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        suggestionTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        //suggestionTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        suggestionTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        addSubview(suggestionTableView)
        
        suggestionTableView.delegate = self
        suggestionTableView.dataSource = self
        suggestionTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            suggestionTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            suggestionTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
            suggestionTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),
            suggestionTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cellHeight*6),
        ])
        hideSuggestions()
    }
    
    func showSuggestions() {
        let sv = suggestionTableView.superview
        sv?.clipsToBounds = false
        suggestionTableView.isHidden = false
    }
    
    func hideSuggestions() {
        suggestionTableView.isHidden = true
    }
    
    @objc func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print(searchBar.text?.uppercased() ?? "")
        showSuggestions()
        possibilities = allPossibilities.filter {$0.contains(searchBar.text?.uppercased() ?? "")}
        print(possibilities.count)
        suggestionTableView.reloadData()
        if searchBar.text == "" || possibilities.count == 0 {
            hideSuggestions()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        hideSuggestions()
    }
}

extension SuggestionSearchBar: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return possibilities.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = suggestionTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.25, green: 0.25, blue: 0.25, alpha: 0.75)
        if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.75)
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = possibilities[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //add method that fills in and searches based on the text in that indexpath.row
        print("selected")
    }
    
}
```

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var searchBar = SuggestionSearchBar(del: self, dropDownPossibilities: ["red","green","blue","yellow"])

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpUI()
    }

    func setUpUI() {
        setUpSearchBar()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    func setUpSearchBar() {
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBar.Style.prominent
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.isTranslucent = false
        searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        searchBar.delegate = self
        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
    }
    
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print(searchBar.text!)
    }
    
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what you really need, but if you want to find out how to use the hitTest, search for UIView Swift hitTest.

Comment: Did you look at the edit I made to the answer for your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67731865/why-isnt-my-uitableview-appearing-when-i-begin-to-type-in-the-custom-uisearchba

Comment: @DonMag sorry, I think I missed that. I just tried it out, but it still isn't allowing me to click on the suggestionTableViewCells. Do you have any other suggestions that might work?

Comment: @ElTomato what do you think I need?

Comment: @helloworld12345 Please check my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing your provided code, I can get the UI to work properly and even get the `UITableViewDelegate` callbacks inside `SuggestionSearchBar`.
Here are the changes

**Suggestion Search Bar**

```
class SuggestionSearchBar: UISearchBar, UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    var suggestionTableView = UITableView(frame: .zero)
    let allPossibilities: [String]!
    var possibilities = [String]()
    var fromController: UIViewController?
    //let del: UISearchBarDelegate!
    
    init(del: UISearchBarDelegate, dropDownPossibilities: [String], fromController: UIViewController) {
        self.fromController = fromController
        self.allPossibilities = dropDownPossibilities
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        delegate = del
        searchTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchBar(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        searchTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_:)), for: .editingDidEnd)
        sizeToFit()
        addTableView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func addTableView() {
        guard let view = fromController?.view else {return}
        let cellHeight = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "").frame.height
        suggestionTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        suggestionTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        //suggestionTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        suggestionTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        view.addSubview(suggestionTableView)
//        addSubview(suggestionTableViewse
        
        suggestionTableView.delegate = self
        suggestionTableView.dataSource = self
        suggestionTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            suggestionTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            suggestionTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            suggestionTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            suggestionTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cellHeight*6),
        ])

        hideSuggestions()
    }
    
    func showSuggestions() {
        let sv = suggestionTableView.superview
        sv?.clipsToBounds = false
        suggestionTableView.isHidden = false
    }
    
    func hideSuggestions() {
        suggestionTableView.isHidden = true
    }
    
    @objc func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print(searchBar.text?.uppercased() ?? "")
        showSuggestions()
        possibilities = allPossibilities.filter {$0.contains(searchBar.text?.lowercased() ?? "")}
        print(possibilities.count)
        suggestionTableView.reloadData()
        if searchBar.text == "" || possibilities.count == 0 {
            hideSuggestions()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        hideSuggestions()
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   lazy var searchBar = SuggestionSearchBar(del: self, dropDownPossibilities: ["red","green","blue","yellow"], fromController: self)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpUI()
    }

    func setUpUI() {
        setUpSearchBar()
    }
}
```

To summarise the changes, the code above tried to add `suggestionTableView`
to the SearchBarView which is not possible so I initialized SearchBarView with the reference to the parent ViewController which is stored as

```
var fromController: UIViewController?
```

This property is later used in `addTableView()`

```
private func addTableView() {
        guard let view = fromController?.view else {return}
        let cellHeight = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "").frame.height
        suggestionTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        suggestionTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        //suggestionTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        suggestionTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        view.addSubview(suggestionTableView)
//        addSubview(suggestionTableViewse

        suggestionTableView.delegate = self
        suggestionTableView.dataSource = self
        suggestionTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            suggestionTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            suggestionTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            suggestionTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            suggestionTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cellHeight*6),
        ])

        hideSuggestions()
    }
```

There is another small change

```
possibilities = allPossibilities.filter {$0.contains(searchBar.text?.lowercased() ?? "")}
```

in `@objc func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {`

**Result**

[image: logs]

[image: Result Gif]

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are adding the `UITableView` as a subview to the `SearchBar` or  `UINavigationBar`, you will keep finding these touch issues.

A possible way to handle this would be have an empty container `UIView` instance at the call site (`ViewController` in your case) and ask `SuggestionsSearchBar` to add it's `tableView` inside that container.

```
SuggestionSearchBar(
    del: self, 
    suggestionsListContainer: <UIStackView_Inside_ViewController>, 
    dropDownPossibilities: ["red","green","blue","yellow"]
)
```

`SuggestionsSearchBar` will still manage everything about the tableView's dataSource, delegate, it's visibility etc. It just needs a view that can hold it's tableView from the call site.

**UPDATE**

I'm highlighting only the relevant parts that need to change - everything else remains the same.

```
class SuggestionSearchBar: UISearchBar, UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    init(del: UISearchBarDelegate, suggestionsListContainer: UIStackView, dropDownPossibilities: [String]) {
        //// All the current setUp
        addTableView(in: suggestionsListContainer)
    }
    
    private func addTableView(in container: UIStackView) {
        //// All the current setUp
        container.addArrangedSubview(suggestionTableView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            suggestionTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cellHeight*6),
            /// We need to assign only height here
            /// top, leading, trailing will be driven by container at call site
        ])
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var suggestionsListContainer: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return stackView
    }()
    
    lazy var searchBar = SuggestionSearchBar(
        del: self,
        suggestionsListContainer: suggestionsListContainer,
        dropDownPossibilities: ["red","green","blue","yellow"]
    )

    func setUpUI() {
        setUpSearchBar()
        setUpSuggestionsListContainer()
    }
    
    func setUpSuggestionsListContainer() {
        self.view.addSubview(suggestionsListContainer)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            suggestionsListContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            suggestionsListContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            suggestionsListContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            /// Height is not needed as it will be driven by tableView's height
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: What code would I need to add in the SuggestionSearchBar class?

Comment: Instead of adding tableView to self `addSubview(suggestionTableView)`, add it to the passed in `suggestionsListContainer` like `suggestionsListContainer.addArrangedSubview(suggestionTableView)`

Comment: Can you write out code in your answer to show how this would be implemented in the ViewController and SuggestionSearchBar

Comment: See **UPDATE** to my answer.

Comment: I tried using this, but the ```suggestionTableView``` that was appearing before, is no longer appearing, is there a reason for this?

Comment: You need to debug this using `View Hierarchy Debugger` and find out at runtime where your views are and what are their frames.

Comment: I changed the zPosition of the ```suggestionTableView ``` and ```suggestionsListContainer ``` and this fixed the visual problem, but it is still not recognizing touches. Do you know why?

Comment: Why don't you use UISearchBar in combination with UISearchController? You'd define UISearchController (which owns the search-bar) and set "self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController". Look here for further details  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/displaying_searchable_content_by_using_a_search_controller